# Small vertical space between bottom caption and the end of the page margin (KOMA)

Tags: captions, margins, alignment, bottom

I am writing my thesis and I learned to love LaTeX even though I'm a real beginner. After all, I almost finished with the work, but I came across the following issue:
I recognized that all the figures and schemes within a floating environment are not exactly aligned with the bottom or top margin of the page (see picture).
`/flushbottom` doesn't seem to change anything. I am using the caption package with:

```
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font={footnotesize,rm},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}
```

The attached picture shows the bottom margin of 2 neighbored pages, one with a bottom -flushed graphic and one with normal text. The gap is small, but it is there.

[image]

This is a very fussy and hardly noticeable issue, but if you know what might be the issue and how to get rid of it globally, feel free to help me out :)

Here is my MWE, I added some two-page text and you have to insert one of your own graphics.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,ngerman,headsepline, footsepline, scrartcl, bibtotoc, liststotoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{document_fontcolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}
\color{document_fontcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\makeatletter
\usepackage{overcite}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font={footnotesize,rm},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Einleitung}
\noindent \textit{\textquotedblleft The structure known, but not yet
accessible by synthesis, is to the chemist what the unclimbed mountain,
the uncharted sea, the untilled field, the unreached planet, are to
other men. The achievement of the objective in itself cannot but thrill
all chemists, who even before they know the details of the journey
can apprehend from their own experience the joys and elations, the
disappointments and false hopes, the obstacles overcome, the frustrations
subdued, which they experienced who traversed a road to the goal.\textquotedblright{}}

\noindent Das vorhergehende Zitat entstammt der seltenen Niederschrift
\textit{Pointers and Pathways in Research} aus dem Jahr 1963 und wurde
von Robert Burns Woodward, einem der bedeutendsten Naturstoffsynthetiker
des 20. Jahrhuversorgung und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen
und Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch
moderne Datierungstechniken bis in das Mit- telpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen.
Durch Grabbeigaben, die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen
zugeordnet werden konnten, lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen
und deren medizinische Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der
Neandertaler nach- weisen.Naturstoffe haben in der Geschichte der
Menschheit schon sehr früh eine bedeutende Rolle in der medizinischen
Versorgung gespielt, wobei sie zur Wversorgung und als Heilmittel
gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden.
Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken bis
in das Mit- telpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nach- weisen.Naturstoffe
haben in der Geschichte der Menschheit schon sehr früh eine bedeutende
Rolle in der medizinischen Versorgung gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung
und als Heil- mittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen
eingesetzt wurden. Diese Prakti- ken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken
bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurück- verfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nachweisen.
versorgung und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen
eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken
bis in das Mit- telpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nach- weisen.Naturstoffe
haben in der Geschichte der Menschheit schon sehr früh eine bedeutende
Rolle in der medizinischen Versorgung gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung
und als Heil- mittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen
eingesetzt wurden. Diese Prakti- ken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken
bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurück- verfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nachweisen.
undversorgung und als Heil- mittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und
Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden. Diese Prakti- ken lassen sich durch
moderne Datierungstechniken bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurück-
verfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben, die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen
zugeordnet werden konnten, lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen
und deren medizinische Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der
Neandertaler nachweisen. hnin (\textbf{8}) im Allgemeinen sowie mit
bereits publizierten \textendash und nur für diese Arbeit relevanten\textendash{}
Synthesen von Strychnin (\textbf{8}) befassen. Da sich diese Dissertationsarbeit
auf die Totalsynthese des natürlich vorkommenden (\textendash )-Enantiomers
fokussiert, wird der Stereodeskriptor (\textendash ) in diesem Kapitel
aus Übersichtsgründen vernachlässigt. Er wird nur dort verwendet,
wo die Chiralität von Strychnin (\textbf{8}) von Relevanz ist, beispielsweise
bei enantioselektiven Synthesen. Im Anschluss werden auch phenolische
Naturstoffe aus Orchideengewächsen (\emph{Orchidaceae}) detailliert
eingeleitet.


\subsection{\noindent Organische Chemie und Naturstoffe}

\noindent versorgung und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen
und Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch
moderne Datierungstechniken bis in das Mit- telpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen.
Durch Grabbeigaben, die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen
zugeordnet werden konnten, lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen
und deren medizinische Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der
Neandertaler nach- weisen.Naturstoffe haben in der Geschichte der
Menschheit schon sehr früh eine bedeutende Rolle in der medizinischen
Versorgung gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung und als Heil- mittel
gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden.
Diese Prakti- ken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken bis
in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurück- verfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nachweisen.
jedoch zweifelsfrei bewiesen werden, dass organische Verbindversorgung
und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen
eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken
bis in das Mit- telpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nach- weisen.Naturstoffe
haben in der Geschichte der Menschheit schon sehr früh eine bedeutende
Rolle in der medizinischen Versorgung gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung
und als Heil- mittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen
eingesetzt wurden. Diese Prakti- ken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken
bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurück- verfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben,
die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten,
lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische
Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nachweisen.
r medizinischen Versorgung gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung
und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen und Entzündungen
eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken
bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen.
\begin{figure}[b]
\noindent \centering{}\includegraphics[width=15.5cm]{\string"Strchnin Numbering\string".png}\caption{\label{fig:Strychnummerierung}Verschiedene Darstellungsweisen (I
und II) von Strychnin (\textbf{8}, links) sowie dessen biogenetische
Nummerierung (rechts). }
\end{figure}
Durch Grabbeigaben, die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen
zugeordnet werden konnten, lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen
und deren medizinische Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der
Neandertaler nachweisen.Naturstoffe haben in der Geschichte der Menschheit
schon sehr früh eine bedeutende Rolle in der medizinischen Versorgung
gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen,
Vergiftungen und Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen
sich durch moderne Datierungstechniken bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum
zurückverfolgen. Durch Grabbeigaben, die zahlreichen Heilkräutern
und Heilpflanzen zugeordnet werden konnten, lässt sich vorhandenes
Wissen über Heilpflanzen und deren medizinische Anwendung an Menschen
bereits zur Zeit der Neandertaler nachweisen.

\noindent Naturstoffe haben in der Geschichte der Menschheit schon
sehr früh eine bedeutende Rolle in der medizinischen Versorgung gespielt,
wobei sie zur Wundversorgung und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen, Vergiftungen
und Entzündungen eingesetzt wurden. Diese Praktiken lassen sich durch
moderne Datierungstechniken bis in das Mittelpaläolithikum zurückverfolgen.
Durch Grabbeigaben, die zahlreichen Heilkräutern und Heilpflanzen
zugeordnet werden konnten, lässt sich vorhandenes Wissen über Heilpflanzen
und deren medizinische Anwendung an Menschen bereits zur Zeit der
Neandertaler nachweisen.Naturstoffe haben in der Geschichte der Menschheit
schon sehr früh eine bedeutende Rolle in der medizinischen Versorgung
gespielt, wobei sie zur Wundversorgung und als Heilmittel gegen Schmerzen,
Vergiftungen und Entzü
\end{document}
```

All the best for you

Comment: we can not comment on your code if you do not show it. It is always best to include a test document (you can use `example-image` or at least show how you set the caption

Comment: I managed to add an MWE. By inserting any graphic, the issue should be visible after compiling the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

If you set

`\usepackage[margin=10pt,font={footnotesize,rm},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}`

with `margin=10pt` you will have a shifted borders of 10pt. Just remove that in to

`\usepackage[font={footnotesize,rm},labelfont={bf,sf}]{caption}`.

Also I recommend you to check and clean your preamble. For example, you loaded `caption` two times, just load the one with options you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I already checked that before and i came across someone telling me that this will only affect the horizontal space. The problem is still present even though the "margin=10pt" was deleted from the preamble.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce your error. For me, it works simply by removing the margin option. Maybe try double-checking that the example you posted exactly reproduces your situation.